# Losing wired connection after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, network-manager, 13.10, wired

Nothing much to say.

After upgrading from 13.04, Ubuntu/Kubuntu holds a wired connection for a few seconds and then drops it. I can untick "Enable networking" on the Network Management tray icon and then tick it again to have the connection back for a few seconds. That's what I'm doing right now to submit this question.

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8001 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 14
       bus info: pci@0000:02:14.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 13
       serial: 00:15:f2:af:bd:44
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=skge driverversion=1.14 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.101 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=31 mingnt=23 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:21 memory:cede4000-cede7fff ioport:c400(size=256) memory:cedc0000-ceddffff
```

**apt-cache policy network-manager**

```
network-manager:
  Installato: 0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22
  Candidato:  0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22
  Tabella versione:
 *** 0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22 0
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**dmesg relevant stuff**

```
    [ 6633.242742] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: disabling interface
[ 6634.485208] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: enabling interface
[ 6636.924409] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[ 6665.947766] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: disabling interface
[ 6666.400297] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: enabling interface
[ 6669.122046] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[ 6789.995899] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: disabling interface
[ 6790.690512] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: enabling interface
[ 6793.140683] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[ 6838.467165] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: disabling interface
[ 6839.413877] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: enabling interface
[ 6841.878607] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[ 6955.304511] eth0: hw csum failure
[ 6955.304530] CPU: 0 PID: 3 Comm: ksoftirqd/0 Tainted: PF          O 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu
[ 6955.304535] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/A8R-MVP, BIOS 0605 12/09/2008
[ 6955.304540]  ffff880135cff162 ffff880139b139e8 ffffffff816e547a ffff880134d66000
[ 6955.304550]  ffff880139b13a00 ffffffff815ec43a ffff88007f724900 ffff880139b13a20
[ 6955.304557]  ffffffff815e5422 0000000000000246 ffff88007f724900 ffff880139b13a30
[ 6955.304565] Call Trace:
[ 6955.304582]  [<ffffffff816e547a>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 6955.304593]  [<ffffffff815ec43a>] netdev_rx_csum_fault+0x3a/0x40
[ 6955.304601]  [<ffffffff815e5422>] __skb_checksum_complete_head+0x62/0x70
[ 6955.304607]  [<ffffffff815e5441>] __skb_checksum_complete+0x11/0x20
[ 6955.304618]  [<ffffffff8167100c>] nf_ip_checksum+0xcc/0x100
[ 6955.304642]  [<ffffffffa0d1c8c2>] tcp_error+0x1b2/0x260 [nf_conntrack]
[ 6955.304650]  [<ffffffff816646e6>] ? fib_table_lookup+0x2e6/0x390
[ 6955.304665]  [<ffffffffa0d183de>] nf_conntrack_in+0xee/0xad0 [nf_conntrack]
[ 6955.304676]  [<ffffffff8135ba9e>] ? cpumask_next_and+0x2e/0x40
[ 6955.304684]  [<ffffffff8135ba9e>] ? cpumask_next_and+0x2e/0x40
[ 6955.304691]  [<ffffffff8135ba9e>] ? cpumask_next_and+0x2e/0x40
[ 6955.304701]  [<ffffffffa0d632f1>] ipv4_conntrack_in+0x21/0x30 [nf_conntrack_ipv4]
[ 6955.304708]  [<ffffffff8161cb5b>] nf_iterate+0x8b/0xa0
[ 6955.304716]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 6955.304722]  [<ffffffff8161cbe4>] nf_hook_slow+0x74/0x130
[ 6955.304729]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 6955.304737]  [<ffffffff81623a74>] ip_rcv+0x344/0x380
[ 6955.304744]  [<ffffffff815eec66>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x646/0x830
[ 6955.304750]  [<ffffffff815eee68>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[ 6955.304756]  [<ffffffff815eeed3>] netif_receive_skb+0x23/0x90
[ 6955.304762]  [<ffffffff815ef940>] napi_gro_receive+0x80/0xb0
[ 6955.304787]  [<ffffffffa002e2e6>] skge_poll+0x3a6/0x870 [skge]
[ 6955.304796]  [<ffffffff8101a395>] ? native_sched_clock+0x15/0x80
[ 6955.304802]  [<ffffffff815ef20c>] net_rx_action+0x11c/0x240
[ 6955.304811]  [<ffffffff81067397>] __do_softirq+0xf7/0x240
[ 6955.304817]  [<ffffffff81067510>] run_ksoftirqd+0x30/0x50
[ 6955.304827]  [<ffffffff8108cadf>] smpboot_thread_fn+0xff/0x1a0
[ 6955.304834]  [<ffffffff8108c9e0>] ? lg_global_unlock+0x60/0x60
[ 6955.304844]  [<ffffffff810847b0>] kthread+0xc0/0xd0
[ 6955.304851]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
[ 6955.304859]  [<ffffffff816f516c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[ 6955.304867]  [<ffffffff810846f0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x120/0x120
[ 6960.694250] eth0: hw csum failure
[ 6960.694268] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: PF          O 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu
[ 6960.694274] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/A8R-MVP, BIOS 0605 12/09/2008
[ 6960.694279]  ffff8801357575e2 ffff88013fc03af0 ffffffff816e547a ffff880134d66000
[ 6960.694288]  ffff88013fc03b08 ffffffff815ec43a ffff880134a09b00 ffff88013fc03b28
[ 6960.694295]  ffffffff815e5422 000000003fc03b70 ffff880134a09b00 ffff88013fc03b38
[ 6960.694303] Call Trace:
[ 6960.694307]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff816e547a>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 6960.694331]  [<ffffffff815ec43a>] netdev_rx_csum_fault+0x3a/0x40
[ 6960.694339]  [<ffffffff815e5422>] __skb_checksum_complete_head+0x62/0x70
[ 6960.694346]  [<ffffffff815e5441>] __skb_checksum_complete+0x11/0x20
[ 6960.694356]  [<ffffffff8167100c>] nf_ip_checksum+0xcc/0x100
[ 6960.694380]  [<ffffffffa0d1c8c2>] tcp_error+0x1b2/0x260 [nf_conntrack]
[ 6960.694387]  [<ffffffff815f0a28>] ? dev_hard_start_xmit+0x318/0x570
[ 6960.694403]  [<ffffffffa0d183de>] nf_conntrack_in+0xee/0xad0 [nf_conntrack]
[ 6960.694412]  [<ffffffff8109edfe>] ? update_group_power+0x13e/0x220
[ 6960.694422]  [<ffffffff8135ba9e>] ? cpumask_next_and+0x2e/0x40
[ 6960.694432]  [<ffffffffa0d632f1>] ipv4_conntrack_in+0x21/0x30 [nf_conntrack_ipv4]
[ 6960.694439]  [<ffffffff8161cb5b>] nf_iterate+0x8b/0xa0
[ 6960.694448]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 6960.694454]  [<ffffffff8161cbe4>] nf_hook_slow+0x74/0x130
[ 6960.694461]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 6960.694468]  [<ffffffff81623a74>] ip_rcv+0x344/0x380
[ 6960.694475]  [<ffffffff815eec66>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x646/0x830
[ 6960.694481]  [<ffffffff815eee68>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[ 6960.694487]  [<ffffffff815eeed3>] netif_receive_skb+0x23/0x90
[ 6960.694493]  [<ffffffff815ef940>] napi_gro_receive+0x80/0xb0
[ 6960.694518]  [<ffffffffa002e2e6>] skge_poll+0x3a6/0x870 [skge]
[ 6960.694525]  [<ffffffff815ef20c>] net_rx_action+0x11c/0x240
[ 6960.694533]  [<ffffffff81067397>] __do_softirq+0xf7/0x240
[ 6960.694539]  [<ffffffff81067675>] irq_exit+0xb5/0xc0
[ 6960.694548]  [<ffffffff816f7516>] do_IRQ+0x56/0xc0
[ 6960.694555]  [<ffffffff816ecb2d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[ 6960.694559]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8104d386>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[ 6960.694574]  [<ffffffff8101b22f>] default_idle+0x1f/0xc0
[ 6960.694581]  [<ffffffff8101baf6>] arch_cpu_idle+0x26/0x30
[ 6960.694590]  [<ffffffff810b54ee>] cpu_startup_entry+0xce/0x280
[ 6960.694598]  [<ffffffff816d4727>] rest_init+0x77/0x80
[ 6960.694607]  [<ffffffff81d26ef7>] start_kernel+0x40a/0x416
[ 6960.694615]  [<ffffffff81d268f6>] ? repair_env_string+0x5c/0x5c
[ 6960.694622]  [<ffffffff81d26120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[ 6960.694629]  [<ffffffff81d265de>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[ 6960.694636]  [<ffffffff81d266e8>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x108/0x117
[ 6982.043414] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: disabling interface
[ 6982.149933] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: enabling interface
[ 6985.178432] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[ 7195.764345] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: disabling interface
[ 7195.884590] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: enabling interface
[ 7198.898305] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[ 7883.869895] eth0: hw csum failure
[ 7883.869913] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: PF          O 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu
[ 7883.869918] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/A8R-MVP, BIOS 0605 12/09/2008
[ 7883.869924]  ffff88004cd96a62 ffff88013fc03af0 ffffffff816e547a ffff880134d66000
[ 7883.869933]  ffff88013fc03b08 ffffffff815ec43a ffff880136885000 ffff88013fc03b28
[ 7883.869940]  ffffffff815e5422 0000000000000000 ffff880136885000 ffff88013fc03b38
[ 7883.869948] Call Trace:
[ 7883.869953]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff816e547a>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 7883.869977]  [<ffffffff815ec43a>] netdev_rx_csum_fault+0x3a/0x40
[ 7883.869985]  [<ffffffff815e5422>] __skb_checksum_complete_head+0x62/0x70
[ 7883.869992]  [<ffffffff815e5441>] __skb_checksum_complete+0x11/0x20
[ 7883.870002]  [<ffffffff8167100c>] nf_ip_checksum+0xcc/0x100
[ 7883.870027]  [<ffffffffa0d1c8c2>] tcp_error+0x1b2/0x260 [nf_conntrack]
[ 7883.870036]  [<ffffffffa0d779f4>] ? __nfqnl_enqueue_packet+0x104/0x160 [nfnetlink_queue]
[ 7883.870051]  [<ffffffffa0d183de>] nf_conntrack_in+0xee/0xad0 [nf_conntrack]
[ 7883.870062]  [<ffffffff81626640>] ? ip_forward_options+0x1c0/0x1c0
[ 7883.870068]  [<ffffffff8161cc22>] ? nf_hook_slow+0xb2/0x130
[ 7883.870075]  [<ffffffff81626640>] ? ip_forward_options+0x1c0/0x1c0
[ 7883.870084]  [<ffffffffa0d632f1>] ipv4_conntrack_in+0x21/0x30 [nf_conntrack_ipv4]
[ 7883.870090]  [<ffffffff8161cb5b>] nf_iterate+0x8b/0xa0
[ 7883.870098]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 7883.870104]  [<ffffffff8161cbe4>] nf_hook_slow+0x74/0x130
[ 7883.870111]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 7883.870118]  [<ffffffff81623a74>] ip_rcv+0x344/0x380
[ 7883.870125]  [<ffffffff815eec66>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x646/0x830
[ 7883.870131]  [<ffffffff815eee68>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[ 7883.870137]  [<ffffffff815eeed3>] netif_receive_skb+0x23/0x90
[ 7883.870144]  [<ffffffff815ef940>] napi_gro_receive+0x80/0xb0
[ 7883.870168]  [<ffffffffa002e2e6>] skge_poll+0x3a6/0x870 [skge]
[ 7883.870174]  [<ffffffff815ef20c>] net_rx_action+0x11c/0x240
[ 7883.870182]  [<ffffffff81067397>] __do_softirq+0xf7/0x240
[ 7883.870189]  [<ffffffff81067675>] irq_exit+0xb5/0xc0
[ 7883.870197]  [<ffffffff816f7516>] do_IRQ+0x56/0xc0
[ 7883.870205]  [<ffffffff816ecb2d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[ 7883.870208]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8104d386>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[ 7883.870223]  [<ffffffff8101b22f>] default_idle+0x1f/0xc0
[ 7883.870229]  [<ffffffff8101baf6>] arch_cpu_idle+0x26/0x30
[ 7883.870238]  [<ffffffff810b54ee>] cpu_startup_entry+0xce/0x280
[ 7883.870246]  [<ffffffff816d4727>] rest_init+0x77/0x80
[ 7883.870256]  [<ffffffff81d26ef7>] start_kernel+0x40a/0x416
[ 7883.870264]  [<ffffffff81d268f6>] ? repair_env_string+0x5c/0x5c
[ 7883.870271]  [<ffffffff81d26120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[ 7883.870278]  [<ffffffff81d265de>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[ 7883.870286]  [<ffffffff81d266e8>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x108/0x117
[ 7902.415764] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: disabling interface
[ 7903.255779] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: enabling interface
[ 7905.693566] skge 0000:02:14.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[ 8019.404373] eth0: hw csum failure
[ 8019.404391] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: PF          O 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu
[ 8019.404396] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/A8R-MVP, BIOS 0605 12/09/2008
[ 8019.404401]  ffff88013748d9e2 ffff88013fc03af0 ffffffff816e547a ffff880134d66000
[ 8019.404411]  ffff88013fc03b08 ffffffff815ec43a ffff88013598a600 ffff88013fc03b28
[ 8019.404417]  ffffffff815e5422 00000000383e2f28 ffff88013598a600 ffff88013fc03b38
[ 8019.404425] Call Trace:
[ 8019.404430]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff816e547a>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 8019.404453]  [<ffffffff815ec43a>] netdev_rx_csum_fault+0x3a/0x40
[ 8019.404462]  [<ffffffff815e5422>] __skb_checksum_complete_head+0x62/0x70
[ 8019.404468]  [<ffffffff815e5441>] __skb_checksum_complete+0x11/0x20
[ 8019.404478]  [<ffffffff8167100c>] nf_ip_checksum+0xcc/0x100
[ 8019.404504]  [<ffffffffa0d1c8c2>] tcp_error+0x1b2/0x260 [nf_conntrack]
[ 8019.404513]  [<ffffffff8101a395>] ? native_sched_clock+0x15/0x80
[ 8019.404522]  [<ffffffff81091b28>] ? resched_task+0x28/0x80
[ 8019.404537]  [<ffffffffa0d183de>] nf_conntrack_in+0xee/0xad0 [nf_conntrack]
[ 8019.404544]  [<ffffffff810925c5>] ? check_preempt_curr+0x85/0xa0
[ 8019.404554]  [<ffffffff8104dee9>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x9/0x10
[ 8019.404562]  [<ffffffff8109484a>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x20a/0x2b0
[ 8019.404572]  [<ffffffffa0d632f1>] ipv4_conntrack_in+0x21/0x30 [nf_conntrack_ipv4]
[ 8019.404580]  [<ffffffff8161cb5b>] nf_iterate+0x8b/0xa0
[ 8019.404588]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 8019.404594]  [<ffffffff8161cbe4>] nf_hook_slow+0x74/0x130
[ 8019.404601]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 8019.404608]  [<ffffffff81623a74>] ip_rcv+0x344/0x380
[ 8019.404615]  [<ffffffff815eec66>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x646/0x830
[ 8019.404621]  [<ffffffff815eee68>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[ 8019.404627]  [<ffffffff815eeed3>] netif_receive_skb+0x23/0x90
[ 8019.404633]  [<ffffffff815ef940>] napi_gro_receive+0x80/0xb0
[ 8019.404659]  [<ffffffffa002e2e6>] skge_poll+0x3a6/0x870 [skge]
[ 8019.404665]  [<ffffffff815ef20c>] net_rx_action+0x11c/0x240
[ 8019.404673]  [<ffffffff81067397>] __do_softirq+0xf7/0x240
[ 8019.404679]  [<ffffffff81067675>] irq_exit+0xb5/0xc0
[ 8019.404687]  [<ffffffff816f7516>] do_IRQ+0x56/0xc0
[ 8019.404695]  [<ffffffff816ecb2d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[ 8019.404698]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8104d386>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[ 8019.404711]  [<ffffffff8101b22f>] default_idle+0x1f/0xc0
[ 8019.404717]  [<ffffffff8101baf6>] arch_cpu_idle+0x26/0x30
[ 8019.404726]  [<ffffffff810b54ee>] cpu_startup_entry+0xce/0x280
[ 8019.404734]  [<ffffffff816d4727>] rest_init+0x77/0x80
[ 8019.404743]  [<ffffffff81d26ef7>] start_kernel+0x40a/0x416
[ 8019.404751]  [<ffffffff81d268f6>] ? repair_env_string+0x5c/0x5c
[ 8019.404758]  [<ffffffff81d26120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[ 8019.404765]  [<ffffffff81d265de>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[ 8019.404772]  [<ffffffff81d266e8>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x108/0x117
[ 8040.634295] eth0: hw csum failure
[ 8040.634314] CPU: 0 PID: 5992 Comm: kwin Tainted: PF          O 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu
[ 8040.634319] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/A8R-MVP, BIOS 0605 12/09/2008
[ 8040.634324]  ffff88007466ac62 ffff88013fc03af0 ffffffff816e547a ffff880134d66000
[ 8040.634334]  ffff88013fc03b08 ffffffff815ec43a ffff8800782fa100 ffff88013fc03b28
[ 8040.634341]  ffffffff815e5422 00000000810925f9 ffff8800782fa100 ffff88013fc03b38
[ 8040.634348] Call Trace:
[ 8040.634353]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff816e547a>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 8040.634377]  [<ffffffff815ec43a>] netdev_rx_csum_fault+0x3a/0x40
[ 8040.634385]  [<ffffffff815e5422>] __skb_checksum_complete_head+0x62/0x70
[ 8040.634392]  [<ffffffff815e5441>] __skb_checksum_complete+0x11/0x20
[ 8040.634402]  [<ffffffff8167100c>] nf_ip_checksum+0xcc/0x100
[ 8040.634428]  [<ffffffffa0d1c8c2>] tcp_error+0x1b2/0x260 [nf_conntrack]
[ 8040.634438]  [<ffffffff8109484a>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x20a/0x2b0
[ 8040.634453]  [<ffffffffa0d183de>] nf_conntrack_in+0xee/0xad0 [nf_conntrack]
[ 8040.634462]  [<ffffffff8109edfe>] ? update_group_power+0x13e/0x220
[ 8040.634472]  [<ffffffff8135ba9e>] ? cpumask_next_and+0x2e/0x40
[ 8040.634483]  [<ffffffffa0d632f1>] ipv4_conntrack_in+0x21/0x30 [nf_conntrack_ipv4]
[ 8040.634490]  [<ffffffff8161cb5b>] nf_iterate+0x8b/0xa0
[ 8040.634499]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 8040.634505]  [<ffffffff8161cbe4>] nf_hook_slow+0x74/0x130
[ 8040.634511]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 8040.634518]  [<ffffffff81623a74>] ip_rcv+0x344/0x380
[ 8040.634525]  [<ffffffff815eec66>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x646/0x830
[ 8040.634531]  [<ffffffff815eee68>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[ 8040.634537]  [<ffffffff815eeed3>] netif_receive_skb+0x23/0x90
[ 8040.634543]  [<ffffffff815ef940>] napi_gro_receive+0x80/0xb0
[ 8040.634568]  [<ffffffffa002e2e6>] skge_poll+0x3a6/0x870 [skge]
[ 8040.634575]  [<ffffffff8109b6a8>] ? update_curr+0x168/0x180
[ 8040.634581]  [<ffffffff815ef20c>] net_rx_action+0x11c/0x240
[ 8040.634589]  [<ffffffff81067397>] __do_softirq+0xf7/0x240
[ 8040.634596]  [<ffffffff81067675>] irq_exit+0xb5/0xc0
[ 8040.634604]  [<ffffffff816f7516>] do_IRQ+0x56/0xc0
[ 8040.634611]  [<ffffffff816ecb2d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[ 8040.634614]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff815b4fd0>] ? acpi_pm_read+0x10/0x20
[ 8040.634630]  [<ffffffff810b7ae8>] ktime_get_ts+0x48/0xe0
[ 8040.634639]  [<ffffffff81082cf1>] posix_ktime_get_ts+0x11/0x20
[ 8040.634647]  [<ffffffff810841c5>] SyS_clock_gettime+0x45/0xa0
[ 8040.634654]  [<ffffffff816f521d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[ 8043.080363] eth0: hw csum failure
[ 8043.080382] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: PF          O 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu
[ 8043.080387] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/A8R-MVP, BIOS 0605 12/09/2008
[ 8043.080392]  ffff880137b6b162 ffff88013fc03af0 ffffffff816e547a ffff880134d66000
[ 8043.080401]  ffff88013fc03b08 ffffffff815ec43a ffff880071b2d800 ffff88013fc03b28
[ 8043.080409]  ffffffff815e5422 00000000815e0673 ffff880071b2d800 ffff88013fc03b38
[ 8043.080416] Call Trace:
[ 8043.080421]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff816e547a>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 8043.080445]  [<ffffffff815ec43a>] netdev_rx_csum_fault+0x3a/0x40
[ 8043.080453]  [<ffffffff815e5422>] __skb_checksum_complete_head+0x62/0x70
[ 8043.080459]  [<ffffffff815e5441>] __skb_checksum_complete+0x11/0x20
[ 8043.080469]  [<ffffffff8167100c>] nf_ip_checksum+0xcc/0x100
[ 8043.080495]  [<ffffffffa0d1c8c2>] tcp_error+0x1b2/0x260 [nf_conntrack]
[ 8043.080504]  [<ffffffff815ddfe7>] ? kfree_skbmem+0x37/0x90
[ 8043.080511]  [<ffffffff815e07da>] ? __kfree_skb+0x1a/0x20
[ 8043.080519]  [<ffffffff8163d4c1>] ? tcp_rcv_state_process+0xac1/0xcc0
[ 8043.080534]  [<ffffffffa0d183de>] nf_conntrack_in+0xee/0xad0 [nf_conntrack]
[ 8043.080543]  [<ffffffff8109edfe>] ? update_group_power+0x13e/0x220
[ 8043.080553]  [<ffffffff8135ba9e>] ? cpumask_next_and+0x2e/0x40
[ 8043.080564]  [<ffffffffa0d632f1>] ipv4_conntrack_in+0x21/0x30 [nf_conntrack_ipv4]
[ 8043.080571]  [<ffffffff8161cb5b>] nf_iterate+0x8b/0xa0
[ 8043.080579]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 8043.080585]  [<ffffffff8161cbe4>] nf_hook_slow+0x74/0x130
[ 8043.080592]  [<ffffffff81623030>] ? inet_del_offload+0x40/0x40
[ 8043.080599]  [<ffffffff81623a74>] ip_rcv+0x344/0x380
[ 8043.080606]  [<ffffffff815eec66>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x646/0x830
[ 8043.080613]  [<ffffffff815eee68>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[ 8043.080619]  [<ffffffff815eeed3>] netif_receive_skb+0x23/0x90
[ 8043.080625]  [<ffffffff815ef940>] napi_gro_receive+0x80/0xb0
[ 8043.080649]  [<ffffffffa002e2e6>] skge_poll+0x3a6/0x870 [skge]
[ 8043.080659]  [<ffffffff8106aea8>] ? bin_uuid+0xd8/0x130
[ 8043.080665]  [<ffffffff815ef20c>] net_rx_action+0x11c/0x240
[ 8043.080672]  [<ffffffff81067397>] __do_softirq+0xf7/0x240
[ 8043.080679]  [<ffffffff81067675>] irq_exit+0xb5/0xc0
[ 8043.080687]  [<ffffffff816f7516>] do_IRQ+0x56/0xc0
[ 8043.080695]  [<ffffffff816ecb2d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[ 8043.080698]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8104d386>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[ 8043.080713]  [<ffffffff8101b22f>] default_idle+0x1f/0xc0
[ 8043.080720]  [<ffffffff8101baf6>] arch_cpu_idle+0x26/0x30
[ 8043.080729]  [<ffffffff810b54ee>] cpu_startup_entry+0xce/0x280
[ 8043.080737]  [<ffffffff816d4727>] rest_init+0x77/0x80
[ 8043.080746]  [<ffffffff81d26ef7>] start_kernel+0x40a/0x416
[ 8043.080754]  [<ffffffff81d268f6>] ? repair_env_string+0x5c/0x5c
[ 8043.080761]  [<ffffffff81d26120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[ 8043.080768]  [<ffffffff81d265de>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[ 8043.080775]  [<ffffffff81d266e8>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x108/0x117
```

I know this question seems to be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/361254/152522, but as you can see from my logs, network-manager has been upgraded directly to the latest version which is assumed to solve this issue.

**UPDATE:** I tried booting Ubuntu 13.10 from a live session and I'm experiencing the same problem, so it's not happening just on Kubuntu. Is there any regression in the kernel? A live 13.04 doesn't show this problem. Also filed [bug #1241897](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1241897).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround is to use an older kernel from raring. I'm using 3.8.0-32 and it works like a charm.

The real solution would be for someone to look into [bug #12341897](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1241897) and fix the regression.

Answer (score 0):

I had also this kind of problem. I was able to solve it partially by unloading and loading the wifi kernel module. In my case the `rtl8192se`.

The commands I used were:

```
modprobe -r rtl8192se
modprobe rtl8192se
```

In your case of a "88E8001 Gigabit Ethernet Controller" it's the driver `skge`.

```
modprobe -r skge
modprobe skge
```

Comment: Thanks, Junio. It seems this bug was fixed upstream. Be sure to use 3.12.0-031200rc6 or higher. :)